# Sql Server Network Configuration Protocols Not Available

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

After installing SQL Server 2008 32 bit, I tried to configure it to allow remote access. So I opened the SSCM (sql server configuration manager) to set the protocols to enabled. I did not find any protocol under the Sql Server Network Configuration...

[image]

I tried repairing, uninstalling and re-installing, registers...
Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: do you have an 32-bit instance installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems you have installed a version that doesn't compatible with target OS, for example enterprise on 7!? but maybe this would help, enabling the TCP protocol and remote connection by T-SQL

```
--step 1: creating a login (mandatory)
create login login_to_system_after_injection with password='Thank$SQL4Registry@ccess';
GO
--step 2: enabling both windows/SQL Authentication mode
/*some server specific configurations are not stored in system (SQL)*/
--set the value to 1 for disabling the SQL Authentication Mode after . . .
exec xp_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2;
--step 3:getting the server instance name
declare @spath nvarchar(256);
--SQL SERVER V100 path, use SQL9 for V90
exec master..xp_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
                 N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL' ,N'SQL10',@spath output,no_output 
--step 4:preparing registry path
declare @insRegPath nvarchar(1024)=N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + 
                                      @spath + '\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp';
--step 5:enabling tcp protocol
exec xp_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @insRegPath, N'Enabled', REG_DWORD, 1 --generally tries to enable all addresses. NOT Recommended
--step 6:enabling remote access
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE --reconfigure is required!
GO
--step 7:a system restart is required in order to enabling remote access.
--step 7.1:shutting down the server
shutdown
--After this command you need to start the server implicitly yourself.
--or just configure the Agent in order to start the server at any shutdown or failure
```

copied from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616114/SQL-Server-T-SQL-Tips-Tricks#xp_regeditwrite

Comment: Note: the article linked in the answer appears to have been deleted.

Comment: article not there

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue when I installed a (second) named instance of SQL server (2016). The default instance is also running on SQL server 2016.

2 things to check:

If you have installed 64bit SQL server, the "SQL Network Configuration (32bit)" section will be empty. You will have to check under "SQL Network Configuration" --- (without the 32bit indication)

In mycase, the "SQL Network Configuration" --- (without the 32bit indication) was not showing up as an option. I was able to see only "SQL Network Configuration (32bit)" which was empty and "SQL Network Configuration" was missing. I did some research and then realised that earlier this server hosted SQL server 2017 instance which was uninstalled after which the 2 X 2016 instances were installed. The server still had the 2017 components like SSMS (sql server management studio) , sscm (sql server configuration manager) etc., I had opened the SQL server configuration manager of 2017 where as my instances are running on SQL server 2016. Later I manually opened SQL server configuration manager (2016) which had "SQL Network Configuration" as expected.

Hope this helps.

Regards, Kishore