# SQL Server 2008 all services running, but Network Configuration is empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I found somthing strange in my SQL Server 2008. I did a full installation of the sql server, after that I found from sql server configuration manager, all the services are running, but the sql server network configuration is empty, this cause remote pc cannot access the sql server database. Cannot figure out what happens.

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post picture.

Can anybody advise me? thanks.

Comment: Have you turned on network connections?

Comment: Yes I turned on network connection, I can ping the sql server using other pc.

Comment: I thought you said you could not connect remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this link, which suggest that **it seems you have installed a version that doesn't compatible with target OS,**

[Sql Server Network Configuration Protocols Not Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984719/sql-server-network-configuration-protocols-not-available)

or [something wrong installation like 32 bit, 64 bit.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/68a3b7e5-cfd4-4ad8-b8e8-b9c1506f628e/sql-2008-missing-server-network-configuration-protocol-32b?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Before this ,please check this option too.

Are you able to connect sqlserver by SSMS(Sqlserver management studio)(if you installed).

Please check several things.

1. `Window + Run` , type `SERVICES.MSC` & enter. Now search all service of **SqlServer** in name column, it is in running mode, if not then run all except **SqlServer Integrated Service** (if you not using this feature).
2. Go to **Configuration Manager**, there is **sqlServerExpress**.

   --go to sqlserver 2008 option , expand there is & enable first 3 only.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ajay2707, I will follow the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I installed a (second) named instance of SQL server (2016). The default instance is also running on SQL server 2016.

2 things to check:

1. If you have installed 64bit SQL server, the "**SQL Network Configuration (32bit)**" section will be empty. You will have to check under "**SQL Network Configuration**" --- (without the 32bit indication)
2. In mycase, the "SQL Network Configuration" --- (without the 32bit indication) was not showing up as an option. I was able to see only "SQL Network Configuration (32bit)" which was empty and **"SQL Network Configuration" was missing**.
          I did some research and then realised that earlier this server hosted SQL server 2017 instance which was uninstalled after which the 2 X 2016 instances were installed. The server still had the 2017 components like SSMS (sql server management studio) , sscm (sql server configuration manager) etc., I had opened the SQL server configuration manager of 2017 where as my instances are running on SQL server 2016. Later I manually opened SQL server configuration manager (2016) which had "SQL Network Configuration" as expected.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Kishore