# Enabling sql server 64 bit for network use -- configuration manager blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql server instance on a machine that I want to open up to being accessible over the network. However, I think there's multiple issues at play here and I'm not sure which one is the real contributing factor.

The version I'm using is:

```
select @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)   Jun 10 2015 03:35:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 14393: )

I believe I need to [enable network configuration in the SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx), but when I look into my manager, I don't see anything of use:

[image]

Is there anything that clearly leaps out as to why this would be blank? Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Well, the `32bit` and not `64bit` jumps out at me first.

Comment: Yeah I'm not fully aware of a way to bring up the configuration manager for the 64-bit instance. As an insurance policy I tried replacing the [sqlcm.xml](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8113a49-3df6-4186-9452-bcdfda348b80/sql-server-configuration-manager-protocol-name-is-blank?forum=sqltools) file from a fresh sql instance, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Are you running the configuration manager from your desktop or from the server? I know, dumb question.

Comment: Running it on the server. I just went through [this exercise to repair a potentially faulty sqlmgmprovider.dll](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/605db435-0816-4c03-a018-ba91d211a411/sql-server-configuration-manager-64bit-server-instance-not-showing?forum=sqlexpress), but still nothing showing up regarding the 64-bit instance.

Comment: Im using a similar version on a fully functional server. When looking in my SQL Server Configutation Manager, my sql server network configuration (32bit) is also empty, so I dont think that is an issue... However I have sql server network configuration WITHOUT the (32bit) aswell, and here I have options. (This is the 64bit option). 
- Is it possible to reinstall sql? It might be you missed some options in the installation process? 
- Check services so all services are started. 
- Does Event Manager say anything?

Comment: Are you sure you've launched CM 2014? I mean, if you have (had) multiple instances on that pc, you could launch by mistake SQL Server 2008 Configuration Manager an it cannot see 2014-instance

Comment: that's a corrupted installation, 64 and 32s bit should be present regardless of your PC's version. re-install necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install SQL Server and/or OS as necessary.

See similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984719/sql-server-network-configuration-protocols-not-available) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108899/sql-server-services-empty-in-sql-server-configuration). What version is your OS? This is possibly an architecture mismatch - 64-bit SQL on 32-bit machine?  Or version mismatch.  SQL Enterprise installed on Windows Home edition?

Yes, you may be able to [troubleshoot](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/909696d9-0c11-4a1b-8cf1-2ce64d3da6ee/sql-server-express-2014-network-configuration-protocols-empty?forum=sqlexpress) and fix, but SQL installs do some heavy lifting.  The best and most thorough solution here is clean up and start fresh.  It will provide you peace of mind.